# C# Instant Messenging

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am creating a program for my work to send out SMS's via a web service I have created.

I want to make it so the SMS replies pop up on a ICQ-like program on each desktop computer that may be over the internet.

How can I push messeges from the service (or otherwise) to a desktop computer program? I could easily make the program just message the web service a CheckForMsgs() every two minutes or whatever.. But this seems inelegant..

Comment: Is you SMS service ONLY web based?  (IE not intented to be used with phone nor any type of mobile device?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop your Applications with [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). here are some helpful links.

- [Real-time Web Applications with SignalR](http://ruwandotnet.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/74/)
- [Asynchronous scalable web applications with real-time persistent long-running connections with SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)